# List All Matches Found in Word Doc

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm able to find the first match in each document that I'm searching, but am unable to list all matches found in each document when there are multiple matches. I've tried multiple ways of iterating through the matches hash table, but can't seem to get it right. Is there a way to do this?

```
$RX = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.|dot|\[dot\]|\[\.\])){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
$WordFiles = Get-ChildItem $Directory -include *.doc, *.docx -recurse
$Directory = "c:\temp"
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application

foreach ($fileSearched in $WordFiles) {
    $objWord.Visible = $false
    $objWord.DisplayAlerts = "wdAlertsNone"
    $objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open("$fileSearched")
    if ($objdocument.Content.Text -match $RX){
        Foreach ($found in $_.Matches) { #| ForEach-Object {$_.Value}
            $file2.WriteLine("{0},{1}",$matches[$_], $filesearched.fullname)  
            write-host $_.matches
            write-host $_.value
            write-host $found
         }
   }
   $file2.close()
}
$objWord.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell's `-match` flavor of regex will only return the first match, and as far as I know there is no way to make it find global matches.

You can however switch to using the `[regex]` class `matches` function which matches globally by default.

`([regex]::matches($objdocument.Content.Text, $RX))`

**UPDATE**

I believe you will also need to switch `$_.Matches` to `$_.Value` per [examples here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/powershell_perl_regex/).

Comment: I tried this one out and received an error: "Unexpected token ':matches' in expression or statement."

Comment: @user2506096 - Updated, can you try with the `::`.

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you! Now I just need to figure out how to iterate through the found matches properly.

Comment: On second thought it seems to enter into the if block even when there shouldn't be any matches in some documents.

Comment: If you can synthesize down to a simple example of running sample text through that is not producing the desired outcome, I might be able to help.

Comment: The example text would be multiple IP addresses in a word document that has other text in it. e.g.  10.10.10.10 this is evaluating as true:    if ([regex]::matches($objdocument.Content.Text, $RX))

Comment: Can you remove the word document portion from this, I need something I can copy-paste into powershell. e.g. `[regex]::matches("STRING_THAT_FAILS", "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.|dot|\[dot\]|\[\.\])){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)")`

Comment: I put a write-host within that IF block and it shows up every time for every file, even ones that do not contain IP addresses. You could use a string with random text as a test. This regular expression definitely works I use it other places in this same script (for text files) and it works without issue. Does that help?

Comment: Amended answer, can you give that shot.

Comment: Still no luck and I try to write-host for $_.matches and $_.value and nothing shows up.

Comment: I'll have to look at this later, might find some time tonight.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the link provided by cchamberlain and came up with:

```
$CSV = "c:\temp\output.csv"
$RX = "(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.|dot|\[dot\]|\[\.\])){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
$WordFiles = Get-ChildItem $Directory -include *.doc, *.docx -recurse
$Directory = "c:\temp"
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$file2 = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($CSV,$true) #Append or Create a new file Stream. 
$file2.WriteLine('Matches,File_Path') # write header

foreach ($fileSearched in $WordFiles) {
    $objWord.Visible = $false
    $objWord.DisplayAlerts = "wdAlertsNone"
    $objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open("$fileSearched")
    $words = ([regex]::matches($objdocument.Content.Text,$RX) | %{$_.value})
        foreach ($word in $words){
            $file2.WriteLine("{0},{1}",$word, $filesearched.fullname)
        }
$file2.close()
$objWord.Quit()
```